# How can I use Reactive Extensions and WCF to process information on a remote server and monitor progress?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, service, windows-services, system.reactive

I am experimenting with using Reactive Extensions to create a Windows Service.

Essentially what I want is for the Observer to sit on the server, the clients able to create observables and have them pushed to the server, the server informing the client of the progress of the job (not sure how to do this or what mechanism to use to do it), and then when it's done, having the server send the client the return code and output of the program it called. Can this be done? Is it the best way to do what I'm trying to do? If you need any more information, what would you need to know to help me?

Comment: Start thinking in events, implement `Observable`s from your events and you will have your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems back to front. Generally *clients* know about servers (how to find then and connect). In contrast the Observer pattern (and therefore Rx) is about allowing something to callback to another observer that is does *not* know about.

In your case I think you simply want to have clients call methods on a server. Potentially these are bound to a single connection/session. The client however maybe an observer of the progress from the server and the final result.

See the [Reactive Trader](http://reactivetrader.com/) project by the team at Adaptive to see a .NET client server app using Rx.